# MongoServerError: BSON field 'update.apiVersion' is an unknown field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here I am using the official mongodb driver btw.

```js
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const CLient = new MongoClient(process.env.uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1});
const db = CLient.db("Discord").collection("Discord");
CLient.connect(err => {
    //const db = CLient.db("Discord").collection("Discord");
    console.log("Connected to the Database")
    //CLient.close();
    const prefix = await db.find({guildid: msg.guild.id});
         await db.updateOne({guildid: msg.guild.id}, {$set: {prefix: newPrefix}});
         if (!prefix) {
             let prefix = db.insertOne({guildid: msg.guild.id, prefix: newPrefix})
             return msg.channel.send(`Your server prefix is now ${newPrefix}`);
         }
     return msg.channel.send(`Your server prefix is now ${newPrefix}`);
});
```

`msg` is already defined here as a object btw and `newPrefix` is also defined. So the database connected successfully according to the logs. The error is thrown when the code is run

`MongoServerError: BSON field 'update.apiVersion' is an unknown field` this is the error msg. How can i fix this

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. This is related to how you instantiate the client - i.e., this won't fail:

```
const Client = new MongoClient(process.env.uri);
```

Comment: I've had a similar error - `MongoServerError: Failed to parse: (...) Unrecognized field 'apiVersion'` and your suggestion helped.

Comment: According to the mongodb documentation: If you specify an API version and connect to a MongoDB deployment that does not support the Stable API, your application may raise an exception when executing a command on your MongoDB deployment. If you use a MongoClient that specifies the API version to query a server that does not support it, your query could fail with an exception message that includes the following text:

'Unrecognized field 'apiVersion' on server...
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/v4.3/fundamentals/stable-api/